# Add dataLabel to Area chart in Highcharts.js

Tags: javascript, charts, highcharts

I want to add a data label to specific point in the 'Area' chart. I'm using 'Highchart' for making graph. I want a data label in chart design as following image. What should I try ? I tried dataLabel defined in 'line' chart but it applies dataLabel to each point in the chart. I want it to be applied for specific point. Also, it should not show value of that point as a dataLabel but it should show series.name on that point. [image]

Comment: You can enable data label on point level, see: http://jsfiddle.net/7kpjmu6r/

Comment: @PawełFus : I tried this. It is working. But it shows value of Y in dataLabel. I want to show the name of series. How should I modify it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the relevant point in your data use the object notation and enabled data labels. You can use [`format`](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#plotOptions.series.dataLabels.format) and [`formatter`](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#plotOptions.series.dataLabels.formatter) to display the desired information.

Example of your series would be:

```
series: [{
    name: 'My series name',
    data: [5, 10, 30, 100, 200, 300, 600,
        { 
            y: 900, 
            dataLabels: {
               enabled: true,
               format: '{series.name}'
            }
        },
        700, 400, 100]
}]
```

Or see [this more elaborate JSFiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/uhbvetcg/).

Comment: Thanks @halvor Strand