# Highcharts. How to series name on line of area?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, charts, highcharts

I can't find an answer inside the documentation:

Series in high charts:

```
 series: [{
        name: 'Asia',
        data: [502, 635, 809, 947, 1402, 3634, 5268]
    }, {
        name: 'Africa',
        data: [106, 107, 111, 133, 221, 767, 1766]
    }, {
        name: 'Europe',
        data: [163, 203, 276, 408, 547, 729, 628]
    }, {
        name: 'America',
        data: [18, 31, 54, 156, 339, 818, 1201]
    }, {
        name: 'Oceania',
        data: [2, 2, 2, 6, 13, 30, 46]
    }]
```

[See jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.9.1/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/demo/area-stacked/)

[Example image](http://take.ms/TLytc)

The question is : how to move series names in the jsFiddle link chart(asia, africa, europe ....) on to the chart from the bottom of the chart?

Comment: you didn't even ask a question...

Comment: And you didn't look very hard... https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/areachart#SimpleExample

Comment: See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29487587/add-datalabel-to-area-chart-in-highcharts-js).

Comment: Ok. Found one. Here it is http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Renderer.text